# search records with text mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to search and display records which is have text.

```
SELECT * FROM question_attempts WHERE `responsesummary`='The compiler would report an error.'
```

It is not displaying the records.
How can i get the records which is having text?

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: What error is it that your getting?

Comment: record having text only "The compiler would report an error."

Comment: Apparently there are not such records. Trust it. It is always right.

Comment: i tried in phpmyadmin. query executing successfully and displaying no records. But i have 6 records

Comment: Hi, Why i'm trying to ask question stackoverflow, it is giving "You have reached your question limit" Is this possible to remove my earlier questions and ask new question? If yes, please guide me. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it:

WHERE responsesummary like '% compiler %'

'compiler' or other words.

Comment: And how can i get the count of this? Where i have to write mysql_num_rows(); function?

Comment: try it?   " select count(1) from ..."

Comment: Hi, Why i'm trying to ask question stackoverflow, it is giving "You have reached your question limit" Is this possible to remove my earlier questions and ask new question? If yes, please guide me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi,
Can anybody help with this.
How to get all the records of current logged in user?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `LIKE` keyword to search for text.

```
SELECT * FROM question_attempts WHERE responsesummary LIKE '%The text to search%';
```

Note that `'%'` is a special character called a wild card.

Comment: Yeah. Its working awesome.
But when i try to display all the records using php code. nothing displaying

Comment: Hurrey. Working fine.

$data1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `question_attempts` WHERE `responsesummary` like '%The element will be set to 0.%'");
 while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($data1)){
 echo $result1 = $row1['responsesummary']."<br />";
 }

Comment: How can i get the count of this? Where i have to write mysql_num_rows() function?

Comment: And is it possible to store all the records which is containing text in one variable?

Comment: could anybody help me to get the count please?

Comment: example : 
"The element will be set to 0" count is 6
"The compiler would report an error" count is 7
"The array size would appropriately grow" count is 3

Comment: Call the `mysql_num_rows` **after** you have called `mysql_query`. 
Example this code:`$rowCount = mysql_num_rows($data1);` 
After execution, `$rowCount` will contain the number of rows retrieved.

You may always get the count from the database directly like so:
`$rowCount = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM question_attempts WHERE responsesummary like '%The element will be set to 0.%'");`

Comment: How to get all the records of current logged in user?

Comment: Can you tell me records from which table? and which field of that table contains the username?

Comment: $query=mysql_query("select * from quiz_grades as grade,user_info_data as info,user as user where user.id=grade.userid 
    and user.id=info.userid and grade.quiz=12 and `fieldid`=1 order by data ASC, grade DESC");

Comment: $USER->id is current logged in user variable

Comment: Try this: `$query=mysql_query("select * from quiz_grades as grade,user_info_data as info,user as user where user.id=grade.userid and user.id=info.userid and grade.quiz=12 and fieldid=1 and user.id=" . $USER->id . " order by data ASC, grade DESC");`
Assuming that _user.id_ is numeric.

Comment: $USER->id is belongings to Bangalore, Bangalore records only should be display, if $USER->id is belongings to Kerala, Kerala records only should be display. No need to display all state ranks.